# Check if window is maximized LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, window

I want to check if the main window is maximized (not fullscreen).

I've already searched up everything in the `Gdx.graphics` class, but couldn't find anything.
The nearest thing I could get, is the `DisplayMode` which doesn't even contain any boolean for the window's maximized property.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

You can directly refer to GLFW from libGDX so from where you launch the desktop, so first capture the window itself on creation with a listener on your `Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration config`.

```
 config.setWindowListener(new Lwjgl3WindowAdapter() {

 @Override
 public void maximized(boolean isMaximized) {
 //You could listen for state changes here as well
 }

 @Override
 public void created(final Lwjgl3Window window) {
 setCurrentWindow(window);

 ...
```

then you can test freely with

`GLFW.glfwGetWindowAttrib(window.getWindowHandle(), GLFW.GLFW_MAXIMIZED);`